# getElementById reference error using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://jsbin.com/nisetupaqa/edit?html,js,console,output

```
 var App = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        )
      }
    })

ReactDOM.render(<App />,getElementById('app-container'));
```

What's wrong? Couldn't get a hello world to work, I got error of `"ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined`

Comment: Try [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e){
    alert("Clicked");
  }
  render(){
      return(
         <h1 onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Hello world</h1>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a method of the `document` object, it isn't a global.

`document.getElementById` will be defined by the browser.

If you want to call `getElementById` as a global, then you have to define it yourself.